# Login flow with ASP.NET and OAuth in Cypress

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, cypress, auth0

Since I couldn't find an answer to my specific question, I thought I'd ask here instead.

The situation is as follows:
I have an application (ASP.NET) that is integrated with Auth0. I'm trying to test the sign-in flow which is set up with authorization code with PKCE OAuth 2.0 flow. What I have in Cypress so far:

1. Navigating to the home page correctly takes me to the auth0 login page.
2. I can submit the form and get redirected to `my.app/callback` which then redirects the user to `my.app/callbackInternal` (Don't ask why - it's an app that I inherited. Most likely to obtain the session ID cookie used by ASP.NET).
3. Unfortunately, upon the redirect, my app returns a 500.

Now, `/callback` is responsible for nothing but returning an HTML document with a JS script that sets the location to `/callbackInternal` by replacing `callback` with `callbackInternal` in the current URL. `/callbackInternal` then accesses `HttpContext.Session` to obtain the code verifier, however, that doesn't seem to exist and the request results in a 500.

All that makes me suspect that the session ID stored by ASP.NET in cookies is not preserved between points 1) and 3). I confirmed that at the time of the redirect, the session ID cookie is set, but I can't seem to be able to verify that it's the same as the one in point 1) since that results in an immediate redirect.

Basically, I'm hoping that someone was in the same situation and knows a solution to this problem.

I have tried verifying session IDs between points 1) and 3). The most likely scenario is that they're different, hence the issue in point 3).

I also have other test scenarios covered with a cookie injection where an access token is obtained programmatically via the API, so I don't need that. I want to test the sign-in flow itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have been also facing a similar problem automating with cypress.  After a through research I come to the solution. I was trying to login in an angular application and my commands were in two different tests.  I just combined all the commands in a single cypress test, which resolved the problem.  Keep all the commands of a form in a single cypress test function may resolve your problem.